# mandrill, merge_vars and handlebars array issue

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mandrill

I am use the HTTP API with mandrill with templates and handlebars support.

If i pass in a single level object wrapped in an array the emails work fine.. as soon as I include a sub array as one of the vars the API bombs and gives me the following error.

```
{ [Error: Error: An invalid value was specified:
{ name: 'cartItems',
  content: [ { slug: 'children', name: 'Children', qty: 2, cost: '5.00' } ] }
This doesn't match the specified type:
{ name: 'string', content: 'string' }] code: 'E_INVALID_TYPE' }
```

my merge_vars look like so:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'totalAmount',
    'content': checkout.amount
  },
  {
    'name': 'eventName',
    'content': checkout.cart[0].name
  },
  {
    'name': 'eventId',
    'content': checkout.cart[0].id
  },
  {
    'name': 'cartItems',
    'content': checkout.cart[0].items
  },
  {
    'name': 'firstname',
    'content': checkout.details.firstname
  },

  {
    'name': 'firstname',
    'content': checkout.details.firstname
  },
  {
    'name': 'lastname',
    'content': checkout.details.lastname
  },
  {
    'name': 'email',
    'content': checkout.details.email
  },
  {
    'name': 'phone',
    'content': checkout.details.phone
  },
  {
    'name': 'username',
    'content': checkout.details.username
  },
]
```

as you can see its bombing out on `cartItems` which is an array of objects basically..

any Ideas? according to [this](http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html#examples) article mandrill with handlebars supports loops

Comment: Do i need to stringify my `cartItems` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is what you posted the full value of your merge_vars parameter? The example JSON from the article you linked (http://kbcdn.mandrill.com/handlebars-example-sendtemplate-api.txt) had something along the lines of:

```
merge_vars: [
  {
    rcpt:"email@address.com", 
    vars:[
      {'name':'cartItems', 'content':checkout.cart[0].items}, 
      ...
    ]
  }
];
```